# number of array elements at compile time

Tags: arrays, swift, compile-time

I want know the number of Array elements at compile time:

```
let sections = ["A","B","C"]

// I want fill later this Array with Arrays of type Product
var productsInSection = [[Product]](count:number of Array elements from sections array, repeatedValue:[])
```

my question is what I can use for: "**number of Array elements from sections array**"
so I don't must have a look, if I change anytime

```
let sections = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

Comment: Are you using a particular programming language?

Comment: If you really need the count at compilation time, reading array from resource file seems to be the most straightforward approach. If that isn't an option I'd try to mix in some Objective C and have some  Macros at precompiled header. The only problem is that I don't see why it would be required in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need "compile time".

But I think [`count` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW19) is sufficient for what you want:

```
let sections = ["A","B","C"]
var productsInSection = [[Product]](count:sections.count, repeatedValue:[])
```

---

Added to answer the comment

For example:

```
private let _indexSectionTitles = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M", "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z", "Ä","Ö","Ü", "#" ]

class MyClass{
    let indexSectionTitles = _indexSectionTitles
    var productsInSection = [[GlobalProduct]](count: _indexSectionTitles.count, repeatedValue: [])
}
```

Comment: class MyClass{

    let indexSectionTitles = [
        "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
        "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
        "Ä","Ö","Ü",
        "#"
    ]
    
    var productsInSection = [[GlobalProduct]](count: indexSectionTitles.count, repeatedValue: [])

I get a compile error:
 'MyClass.Type' does not have a member named 'indexSectionTitles'

Comment: Thank you!!
The trick was to put it outside the class declaration. Now it works for me!